# CakePHP3 CRUD API Authorisation error

Tags: cakephp, crud

I'm CakePHP 3.x with the FOC CRUD plugin to provide an API.

I am using some Angular in my front-end, calls are made to the Cake API via http requests which works as expected.

However when I try to call the API form a Cake controller, the same method that works when called from the Angular controller is denied when called from the Cake controller. I am using:

```
$http->put('http://foo.com/messages/update/'.$id.'.json', ['Messages' => ['id' => $id, 'action' => 'read']]);
```

If I add the 'update' method to the allow list the PUT method is allowed access and performs the update. There is already an Auth session active but it seems when Cake makes the http request it doesn't recognise that there is already a live auth session.

I could solve this if I could make the api call via a local path but I'm not sure this is possible as with out the 'http://foo.com' I get a "malformed URI" error. Any ideas?

Comment: And you have configured the HTTP client to pass the information required for the request to be authenticated (like a session cookie for example)?

Comment: @ndm No, I'm not passing anything Auth information. The Angular request is a plain 'put' request which works without, but the Cake http request is doing something different because it requires some Auth data. The same request, same data, different results.

Comment: How can you tell that the angular request doesn't pass any such information? Have you explicitly disabled `withCredentials`, and/or inspected that the request is being sent without any auth info? From the details provided it sounds as if the `update` method generally requires authentication, so if the angular request works, then it surely must sent some kind of auth info, which your PHP based request is lacking.

Comment: The Angular is running on the same CakePHP app, I use it for some basic view functionality (deleting a message for example). I've not configured any credentials with Angular so I fail to see how any authorisation could be occurring. Instead it seems that the current Auth session is recognised when Angular makes the request.

Comment: The session is being recognized because the request initiated by Angular passes the required authentication information. Angular uses `XmlHttpRequest`, which will send cookies and other auth info by default, unless it's a cross domain request (which requires `withCredentials` to be enabled).

Comment: I have now added XMLHttpRequest headers to CakePHP PUT request, still no go though

Comment: What do you mean by "added XMLHttpRequest headers"? I'd suggest you have a look at **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#authentication** and **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#setting-and-managing-cookies**. ps, I'm not a FOC CRUD expert, I don't know whether there might be a recommended way to handle "internal API calls", usually I'd have the logic in the model layer, and commicate with it directly from wherever I want.